# Masking between Pandas dataframes where index doesn't match

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

**The Goal**

Perform a combination of 2-sample t-tests between 2 dataframes: a boolean matrix that sets the True/False context, and a matrix of values.  The combination happens between rows that don't share an index, and I cannot think of how to apply a mask from one index in one df to a mismatching index in another df.

**Example**

Dummy data:

```
cnv = {'gene': ['a','b','c'],
        'cell_1': [0,-1,0],
        'cell_2': [0,-1,-1],
        'cell_3': [-1,0,-1],
        'cell_4': [-1,0,-1],
        'cell_5': [-1,0,0]
       }
cnvdf = pd.DataFrame(cnv)
cnvdf.set_index('gene', inplace=True)

cnv_mask = cnvdf < 0

rna = {'gene': ['x','y','z'],
        'cell_1': [1, 5, 8],
        'cell_2': [8, 5, 4],
        'cell_3': [8, 6, 1],
        'cell_4': [1, 2, 7],
        'cell_5': [5, 7, 9],
       }
rnadf_all = pd.DataFrame(rna)
rnadf_all.set_index('gene', inplace=True)
```

Here are the two dfs:

```
print(rnadf)
      cell_1  cell_2  cell_3  cell_4  cell_5
gene                                        
x          1       8       8       1       5
y          5       5       6       2       7
z          8       4       1       7       9

print(cnv_mask)
     cell_1 cell_2 cell_3 cell_4 cell_5
gene                                   
a     False  False   True   True   True
b      True   True  False  False  False
c     False   True   True   True  False
```

Pseudocode of what I wish to accomplish:

```
for rR in rnadf_all.iterrows():
        for cR in cnv_mask.iterrows():
            link = rR+"&"+cR
            rnaPos = rR[<True values from cR mask applied to rR>].dropna()
            rnaNeg = rR[<False values from cR mask applied to rR>].dropna()
            t, p = stats.ttest_ind(rnaPos, rnaNeg)
```

**Desired Product**

This is what it would ideally look like if you were to run the pseudocode above with the supplied answers, printing the `link` and `rnaPos` and `rnaNeg` values for each iteration:

```
link   rnaPos   rnaNeg
x&a    [8,1,5]  [1,8]
x&b    [1,8]    [8,1,5]
x&c    [8,8,1]  [1,5]
y&a    [6,2,7]  [5,5]
y&b    [5,5]    [6,2,7]
...
...
...
z&c    [4,1,7]  [8,9]
```

Above is the pattern I'm looking for.  Eg: `z&c`, mask from row `c` in `cnv_mask` applied to row `z` in `rnadf_all`, creating `True` values `[4,1,7]`, and `False` values `[8,9]`.  So the application isn't matching masks by indexes between dfs, its matching masks by column alignment.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import itertools
for pr in itertools.product(rnadf_all.index, cnv_mask.index):
    print('&'.join(pr), rnadf_all.loc[pr[0]][cnv_mask.loc[pr[1]]].tolist(),
          rnadf_all.loc[pr[0]][~cnv_mask.loc[pr[1]]].tolist())

x&a [8, 1, 5] [1, 8]
x&b [1, 8] [8, 1, 5]
x&c [8, 8, 1] [1, 5]
y&a [6, 2, 7] [5, 5]
y&b [5, 5] [6, 2, 7]
y&c [5, 6, 2] [5, 7]
z&a [1, 7, 9] [8, 4]
z&b [8, 4] [1, 7, 9]
z&c [4, 1, 7] [8, 9]
```

itertools.product gives all possible products. For each of them, `rnadf_all.loc[pr[0]][cnv_mask.loc[pr[1]]].tolist()` goes to the corresponding row in `rnadf_all` and slice that by the true values in the corresponding row of `cnv_mask`. And for the False values, you just need to put a tilde in front of `cnv_mask`.

Comment: Ahh yes, the Cartesian product.  Thanks for reminding me of that.  Off hand, do you know if `.loc` is equivalent (performance wise) to a dictionary lookup?

Comment: I don't think so Dictionaries should be much faster. Testing on the index of a 1000-row df `%timeit df.loc['r970']` -> `64.5 µs` vs zipped (index,col) dictionary `%timeit d['r970']` -> `36.1 ns`